# Vapor 3: multiple server sockets in one app

Tags: swift, vapor

I would like to implement a server app in Swift, with two listening (server) sockets with different functionality sets exposed. The app itself is a kind of smart proxy - transformer of data between the two sockets, with a little persistence thrown in. I have tried to prototype the app in Vapor, but it seems that multiple server sockets in a single app is somewhat an unexpected use case. [Doc suggests](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/application/) that `Application` container is a singleton, it has a single `runningServer` property, and it takes a single `Services` struct where `Router` is registered - where i would need practically two separate routers. Now i'm having some ideas, involving either multiple Vapor Applications inside "my application", or some usage of `subContainer`s, though i don't know how exactly the service registry sharing works. Or maybe something around Providers which i don't fully understand either. But in any case, it all feels like that i'm fighting against a clean design decision of "1 app = 1 server". Anyone prove me wrong?

Comment: I think your conclusion is correct. However, have you seen this Vapor docs page: https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/websocket/ ? Could you implement your requirement by listening on the same socket but using socket routing (as described on the same page) to give you the different functionality sets?

Comment: @Nick thank you for the warm light ray of curiosity in the overall internet darkness :-) One of the sockets is expected to be used only by clients on the same machine, e.g. localhost. So two sockets model allows for shifting some of the security to OS level, while single socket would depend on application code. We also considered the 21st century design: multiple Vapors as separate services with some messaging between, but the typical deployment will be an existing 3rd party server, so we must keep low profile of the solution.